# QGIS fill column of attribute with information

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have two columns in a attribute table.

The first one has numbers from 1 to 30 in different frequencies. For example number 1 20 times, 2 35 times and so on.

In the second column I want to write for every number (all frequencies) a specific code of strings. 
For example All 1 = abc, all 2 = def...

My first step is to separate the number of interest (in picture below it's number 5)

[image]

But after this I have problems to find a way to fill the second column with the specific code for the number (in picture's case all 5 should be BWk) automatically.

I can write the specific code in every single row of the code's columns but's that's to much work.

Maybe someone can help me with an advice of what can I do with the field calculator to get through it.

Maybe it's possible with copy & paste but I don't find out yet how I can selected more cells simultaneous and paste some information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the field calculator try this:

update your field **Code** with this:

```
if("DN" = 5, 'BWk', "Code")
```

what it does is:

- Check if the value of your first field **DN** is *5*
- if this is true it will set the value in **Code** to *BWk*
- if the statement is false ( **DN** is for example *42*) it will leave **Code** as it is

Take note of the single and double quotation. Single quotations are strings/text while double quotations are fields

Comment: Great. It works! Thank you for the code and for the explanations,either!!